# How to prevent widget from shrinking to its content's size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In the code I am writing, I create some frames and put them in place as in the example. The hierarchyframe has a set width of 260. When I put in a label with width less than that of the frame, the frame's width diminishes to that of the label.

The code is below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Application")
root.geometry("1200x1000")

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure('TFrame', background='gray')
s.configure('windowframes.TFrame', background='darkgray')

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="2 2 2 2",height=300)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,E,S,W))

toolframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,height=60,style='windowframes.TFrame')
toolframe.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2,sticky=(N,S,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)

hierarchyframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,width=260,style='windowframes.TFrame')
hierarchyframe.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=2, sticky=(N,S,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)
label = Label(hierarchyframe,text="sample")
label.grid(column=0, row=0)

graphicframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,style='windowframes.TFrame')
graphicframe.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N,S,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)

fileframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,height=360,style='windowframes.TFrame')
fileframe.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(N,S,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)

mainframe.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The styles are there so you can see the outline of the frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that you need to tell the `Frame` to not *propagate* it dimensions, meaning not adjust itself to fit its contents. You can prevent it from happening by using the `grid_propagate()` method as shown below:

```
...
toolframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,height=60,style='windowframes.TFrame')
toolframe.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2,sticky=(N,S,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)
hierarchyframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,width=260,style='windowframes.TFrame')
hierarchyframe.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=2, sticky=(N,S,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)
hierarchyframe.grid_propagate(False)  # <=== ADDED ====
label = Label(hierarchyframe,text="sample")
...
```

Here's a screenshot showing the result:

[image: screenshot]

Another alternate would be to use set the column's minimum size in pixels like the following which would not prevent it from getting wider:

```
hierarchyframe.columnconfigure(0, minsize=260)
```